# How to insert a link to user profile or chat in message using telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, hyperlink, telethon

Composing new message in telethon I'm trying to make something like 'User (link) in chat (link) posted something', but failed.

According to https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Special-links, I've tried links like tg://user?id=123 and tg://openmessage?chat_id=123, but that gives links in text that are not working.

Here's the example:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    sender = await event.get_sender()
    sender_id = event.sender_id
    sender_link = 'tg://user?id=' + str(sender_id)
    payload = '[%s] (%s) said something' % (sender.first_name, sender_link)
```

I'm expecting a message with hyperlinked username, but getting [Alex] (tg://user?id=123), and that link leads to nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the space between `[...]` and `(...)`. You should have `[%s](%s)`.

Comment: Yep, that worked. But link to chat is still broken. I'm using tg://openmessage?chat_id=123, am I wrong?

Comment: `tg://openmessage?chat_id=123&message_id=456` reads "*Should* go". It might not work. If I recall, recent versions of official clients support `https://t.me/c/{chat_id}/{msg_id}` to go to a different chat. Note that the `{msg_id}` doesn't seem to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

Twit is right, but there are several alternatives. You can manually insert a MessageEntityMention to the parser, or you can use HTML parse_mode and the  format. Note that both of these are better, consider for example a user named `hello](tg://user?id=321)[`. This user would not get a link, so you should avoid markdown as it's not possible to escape this.

Comment: You should consider adding an example on how to do both, given `client.send_message` does not support (at the time of writing) manually specifying entities such as `MessageEntityMention`. In addition, manually setting entities is very error prone. Things like emoji will make it easy to get the `offset` and `length` wrong. So, HTML is the safest choice.

Comment: True manually specifying entities is difficult to get right, but its quite easy to do statically: `client.send_message("bold italic", lambda x: return [MessageEntityBold(0, 4), MessageEntityItalic(5, 6)])`